# I have animated right and left scroll effect for list items in Flutter but the whole list changes at once?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm doing an app on Flutter. I created a list for my app and created a right scroll effect on my list. But when I move an item in the list to the right, all the elements in the list shifts to the right. Likewise when I move it to the left, it shifts to the left. There are ready-made tools for this **(flutter_slidable)** but I want to create a more specific list item. I am also adding my codes and the current work. Thank you in advance if anyone has a solution on this issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNOHZ.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfcgN.jpg)

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var horizontalDrag = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 3,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
              height: 75,
              width: 360,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                    left: 10,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        print("index $index");
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: 80,
                        height: 50,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                        child: Align(
                          child: Padding(
                            child: Icon(Icons.add),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                          ),
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      print("index $index");
                    },
                    child: AnimatedContainer(
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                        child: Listener(
                          onPointerMove: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              if (value.delta.dx.isNegative == true) {
                                horizontalDrag = 0.0;
                              } else {
                                horizontalDrag = 50.0;
                              }
                            });
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: horizontalDrag),
                            width: 200,
                            height: 50,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.red,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                "Try $index",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, the variable used to save the dragging position is only one, while the `List` contains three elements.
The solution is to use a `List` of `double`, to store the dragging position of each element:

```
List<double> horizontalDrag = [0, 0, 0];
```

It would be needed to store the `horizontalDrag` relative to each element in the `onPointerMove` callback:

```
onPointerMove: (value) {
 setState(() {
   if (value.delta.dx.isNegative == true) {
     horizontalDrag[index] = 0.0;
   } else {
     horizontalDrag[index] = 50.0;
   }
 }
);
```

And display the element accordingly:

```
Container(
 margin:
     EdgeInsets.only(left: horizontalDrag[index]),
),
```

This is a screenshot of the result:
[image: screenshot]

Follows a full working example:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<double> horizontalDrag = [0, 0, 0];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 3,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
              height: 75,
              width: 360,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                    left: 10,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        print("index $index");
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: 80,
                        height: 50,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                        child: Align(
                          child: Padding(
                            child: Icon(Icons.add),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                          ),
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      print("index $index");
                    },
                    child: AnimatedContainer(
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                        child: Listener(
                          onPointerMove: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              if (value.delta.dx.isNegative == true) {
                                horizontalDrag[index] = 0.0;
                              } else {
                                horizontalDrag[index] = 50.0;
                              }
                            });
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            margin:
                                EdgeInsets.only(left: horizontalDrag[index]),
                            width: 200,
                            height: 50,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.red,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                "Try $index",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was exactly what I wanted. I have been dealing with this problem for 3 days. It was finally resolved.

Comment: Happy to help! Don't forget to select the answer as correct